# Get date from calendar

Tags: java, calendar

Hi everyone in my program i receive a date like:
2015-01-18

It's a calendar object and i need to get the day, month and the year from the object. Right now i do something like:

```
int day = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = date.get(Calender.MONTH + 1);
int year = date.get(Calender.Year);
```

The output is:

```
day = 18
month = 1
year = 2015
```

My problem is that i wanna get the month in this case like 01 and not 1 because that value is parsed later on my code and needs to be on that format. Is ugly to append the 0 before that 1 so anyone knoenter code herews a better way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `SimpleDateFormat`? And why are you *parsing* the value again in your code, when you've already got it as an `int`? Ideally, you should keep the value as a date/time-related type to start with, rather than converting it to a string and parsing it back... only do that when you really have to. (I'd recommend using Joda Time if you're using Java 7 or older, and java.time if you're using Java 8+, rather than java.util.Calendar.)

Comment: I have to use Calendar i can't change that. I use java 6 and i can't change that too. After i read the day, month and year and i have to pass it to another object to execute a webservice and it must be 01.

Comment: Well then you need to pass the string, not an int, and that's not really "later on my code" if you're passing it to a web service.

Comment: MONTH+1 == WEEK_OF_YEAR

Comment: Are you planning to follow up on this?

Answer (score 6):

If you need to pass the data as "01" an `int` is the wrong datatype. You need to pass it as a `String`. You can format the date using `SimpleDateFormat`. That way you can choose which elements to pick from the date and the format they should have. Example:

```
final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
final Date date = calendar.getTime();
String day = new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(date);    // always 2 digits
String month = new SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(date);  // always 2 digits
String year = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(date); // 4 digit year
```

You can also format the full date like this:

```
String full = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date); // e.g. 2015-01-18
```

The [JavaDoc for SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) fully explains the various formatting options. Please note that `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe.

Answer (score 4):

You need to

```
int month = cal.get(Calender.MONTH) + 1; // 0..11 -> 1..12
```

to get the int for the month (the + must be outside the argument).

If you need a string with a leading zero from that integer, you can use textformat:

```
System.out.printf("month=%02d%n", month);
String monthStr = String.format("%02d", month);
```

But, you actually do not have to take the route via ints, you can directly format parts of a `Date` into strings:

```
monthStr = new SimpleDateFormat("MM", Locale.ENGLISH).format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: You mean `date.getTime()`, given that `date` is a `Calendar`, not a `Date`

Comment: Yes, correrct (and yes it is pretty funny to call "getTime on a Calendar named date to get a Date" :)